# Create a vector in R from a list with different column lengths

Tags: r, vector

The question says to "Save the weights of the chicks on day 4 from diet 1 as a vector x. Save the weights of the chicks on day 4 from diet 4 as a vector y"

My code:

```
data("ChickWeight")
plot(ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$weight, col=ChickWeight$Diet)
head(ChickWeight)
chick <- reshape(ChickWeight, idvar=c("Chick","Diet"), timevar="Time",direction="wide")
head(chick)
chick <- na.omit(chick)

#Exercise1
library(dplyr)
x <- filter(chick,Diet=="1")%>%select(chick$weight.4)%>%unlist
y <- filter(chick,Diet=="4")%>%select(chick$weight.4)%>%unlist
```

[The error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz8fy.png)

The error in code:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Locations 59, 58, 55, 56, 48, etc. don't exist.
i There are only 14 columns.
```

Not sure why this error occurs since I'm converting it to a vector. Can someone please inform me on the solution to this? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

We don't the `chick$` in `select` - just use the unquoted column name

```
library(dplyr)
filter(chick, Diet == "1")%>%
   select(weight.4) %>%
   pull(1)
```

Comment: What does pull(1) do?

Comment: Can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362597/how-to-sort-multiple-columns it is not a duplicate question

Comment: @user330 sure, will cheeck out

Answer (score 0):

Okay I actually immediately fixed it lol. Noob mistake, but if anybody comes across this error in their starting of R, the solution is to remove the list name, instead of chick$weight.4 just put weight.4 :)